# Using time.sleep to Update Wxpython GUIs without GUI "Freezing"

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I have three separate GUIs that I wrote using wxpython.

```
def __init__(self, app):
    self.gui1= Gui1(None)
    self.gui1.Show()
    self.gui2= Gui2(None)
    self.gui2.Show()
    self.run_game()

def run_game(self):
    for i in range(0, 100):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.gui1.method1()
        self.gui2.method1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    controller = Controller(app)
    app.MainLoop()
```

However, when I run this code, the GUIs don't display and appear to "freeze."  Could someone please help with this?

Comment: Without seeing what method1 I would say it is due to that loop of 100 x 0.5 seconds, during that time the UI will not be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `time.sleep`. It blocks the main loop. Instead, use a `wx.Timer()`. They run in their own event loop that is non-blocking. You can read the documentation [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Timer-class.html) or check out the following tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/